# Possible to have 2 after_create callbacks in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an ActiveRecord model with a callback, such as:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :add_new_employee_bonus

  private
  def add_new_employee_bonus
    self.bonus += 100
  end
end
```

Am I allowed to have 2 callbacks? The Rails documentation doesn't make this clear:

```
after_create :add_new_employee_bonus, :another_callback_method
```

I could try it, of course, but I want to make sure this is officially supported even if it does happen to work.

Using latest Rails (3.2.11 as of now), but if this is supported in Rails 4 that's good enough for me.

***UPDATE***: I did try the above and it works fine, I just want some kind of evidence this is supported.

Comment: there is no problem with that

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is supported. I don't know specifically about rails 4, but I can't imagine they changed that.

Comment: How do you know it's supported?

Comment: I don't, as I said. But I couldn't find anything in [the release notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html) that would indicate deprecation.

Comment: I meant how do you know it's supported in 3.2?

Comment: I have used it, it worked fine, and have never seen any other way of doing it. It is an indicator, not proof - decide for yourself if this is satisfactory.